# Fourier Series of what appears to be a sawtooth series

Tags: functions, fourier-series

> Find the Fourier series of

\begin{equation} 
f(x)=\begin{cases} x-[x] \quad &\text{if $x$ is not an integer} \\ \frac{1}{2} \quad &\text{if $x$ is an integer} \end{cases}
\end{equation}

I fail to see what interval I should integrate over in order to find its Fourier series.

Comment: What is the period of this function?  Once you have that, you may integrate over any interval of the form $[x,x+P]$

Comment: $f$ has period $1$, so $[0,1]$ is a viable choice. Use $e^{2\pi i n x}$, resp. $\cos (2\pi nx)$ and $\sin (2\pi nx)$ then.

Comment: Integrate over the period of the function.

Comment: The second part of the piecewise definition will not influence the answer.  If you'd put any number there besides $1/2$, the Fourier series would still be the same.

Comment: So what you are saying is that I should calculate the following integral: $\int_{0}^{1}xe^{2\ppi i n x}dx$.

Comment: You need to integrate over the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a picture:

[image]

from which we can see it is period 1. So just work the problem on $[0,1]$.

---

**Edit/update:** Since you want a *full* Fourier series, you want to work with a symmetric interval about the origin, say $-1<x<1$ here. The plot of $f(x)$ there would look like

[image]

Then, the (complex form) of the full Fourier series is given by

$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n \exp(in\pi x) \quad\text{where}\quad
c_n={1\over 2}\int_{-1}^{1} f(x)\exp(-in\pi x)\,dx.
$$

Here's a plot taking the partial sum ranging over $n=-10$ to $n=10$ (red) along with the graph of $f(x)$ (black):

[image]

Comment: So just to be clear; you are saying that: $c_{n}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{-inx}dx =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}xe^{-inx}dx =\frac{e^{-in}(1+in)-1}{n^{2}}$. Or?

Comment: Do you want a full Fourier series or just a Fourier sine or cosine series?

Comment: I want a full Fourier series.

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer...

Comment: Wonderful! Just wonderful! May I ask what kind of program you used to plot the Fourier series?

Comment: I used *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{equation} 
f(x)=\begin{cases} x-[x] \quad &\text{if $x$ is not an integer} \\ \frac{1}{2} \quad &\text{if $x$ is an integer} \end{cases}
\end{equation}

The question doesn't seem to be so much about finding the Fourier series as about figuring out what this function looks like.  Let's try a few values:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
x & f(x) \\
\hline
0.1 & 0.1 \\
0.3 & 0.3 \\
0.5 & 0.5 \\
0.7 & 0.7 \\
0.9 & 0.9 \\
1.1 & 0.1 \\
1.3 & 0.3 \\
1.5 & 0.5 \\
1.7 & 0.7 \\
1.9 & 0.9 \\
2.1 & 0.1 \\
2.3 & 0.3 \\
2.5 & 0.5 \\
2.7 & 0.7 \\
2.9 & 0.9 \\
3.1 & 0.1 \\
3.3 & 0.3 \\
3.5 & 0.5 \\
3.7 & 0.7 \\
3.9 & 0.9
\end{array}
$$
**There is a pattern here! You WILL see the pattern if you carefully graph these points.**  Don't worry about Fourier series before you've seen this basic point.  Any putative attempt to think about the Fourier series of this function would be phoney if you haven't seen this simple pattern.